# CustomerAdapter Error

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to apply a custom adapter to my application main activity.

The main activity code :

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity{
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int packageNumber=10;

        Integer[] imageId=new Integer[packageNumber];
        String[] title=new String[packageNumber];
        String[] text=new String[packageNumber];

        int j=0;
        imageId[j]=R.drawable.tick;
        title[j]="AppName";
        text[j]="AppPackage";
        j++;

        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(ActivityMain.this,imageId,title,text);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);// Error here
    }
}
```

The adapter code :

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity _context;
    private final String[] _title;
    private final String[] _text;
    private final Integer[] _imageId;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context,Integer[] imageId,String[] title,String[] text) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_applications,text);
        this._context = context;
        this._title = title;
        this._text = text;
        this._imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_applications, null, true);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView firstLine = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

        imageView.setImageResource(_imageId[position]);
        firstLine.setText(_title[position]);
        txtTitle.setText(_text[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And the error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 9457
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.app.ActivityMain.onCreate(ActivityMain.java:150)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

There is probably an non-initialized var or something like that but I can't find where. What's wrong with my code ?

Thanks for your help.

Edit :

The fragment_activity_main :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml file, `list` is null when you call `setAdapter()`.

Comment: Yes this is a copy error. Note that I cut the code but tis is a tab application so I have activity_main.xml and fragment_atcivity_main.xml which is the latest used.

Comment: Can you post the Fragment code where you inflate fragment_activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference`

Firstly you're using

`R.layout.activity_main` in the `setContent()` method of your activity, while the `ListView` is in `fragment_activity_main`

If the xml file which you've posted is not `activity_main` then change it in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity_main);`

Also
You're using a class name as the name of ID

change

`android:id="@+id/ListView"`

to

`android:id="@+id/listview"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the code with `setAdapter()` in the main Activity, when you should have it in the Fragment that will use it.

The problem is that `list` is null because `R.id.ListView` is not visible in the current Content View.

So, wherever you inflate `fragment_activity_main.xml` is where you should be calling `setAdapter`.

So, it would be in your Fragment code:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_main, container, false);

      int packageNumber=10;

      Integer[] imageId=new Integer[packageNumber];
      String[] title=new String[packageNumber];
      String[] text=new String[packageNumber];

      int j=0;
      imageId[j]=R.drawable.tick;
      title[j]="AppName";
      text[j]="AppPackage";
      j++;

      list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
      CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),imageId,title,text); //use getActivity() for the context
      list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Not working but I understand now what's the problem. The best way is to put the code in the specific fragment ant not in the activity "root".

Comment: @Mathieu Yeah, you may need to re-factor other code as needed, but you get the idea.